# mp3 audio not playing on wp7 device via isolatedstorage but works on emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

Quite strange that code works fine on emulator but not on device. 
I am downloading an mp3 via http and storing it on isolatedstorage before I play it. 
Its like I am caching it forever. Next time if I have to play that mp3 again I simply do it from isolatedstorage. 
Now that seems to work on emulator but on device I am getting an error thrown by MediaElement (myMedia_MediaFailed function getting called). 
Debugger shows that file it is trying to play has the right size yet the error is there. 
I have 7.0 OS of WP7 and can't seem to find any tool which would let me at least grab the mp3 from isolatedstorage to play on PC just to see if file got saved fine. 
Under mywebClient_OpenReadCompleted function here is the code

```
isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

bool checkQuotaIncrease = IncreaseIsolatedStorageSpace(e.Result.Length);

string audioFileName = "audiofile.mp3";

isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(audioFileName, FileMode.Create, isolatedStorageFile);
long audioFileLength = (long)e.Result.Length;
byte[] byteImage = new byte[audioFileLength];
e.Result.Read(byteImage, 0, byteImage.Length);
isolatedStorageFileStream.Write(byteImage, 0, byteImage.Length);
isolatedStorageFileStream.Flush();

AudioPlayer.SetSource(isolatedStorageFileStream);
AudioPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Able to verify that file downloaded on the device plays fine on PC. This was achieved via ISETool.exe for which I needed to upgrade to SDK 7.1 RC. Using the tool I was able to grab the downloaded mp3 from device to PC.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to close Zune once the app is deployed on the phone?

Medias can't play when the Media Library is locked and Zune locks it.

If it solves your problem, you can use WPConnect.exe to debug your app without Zune (more info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/03/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect.aspx)).